# Capture url parameter at the end of session con spring security

Tags: java, model-view-controller, primavera

I'm working with Spring Security 3.2 and Hibernate 4. Currently I have a custom login wich works as follows . The URL `"/"` (root ) is a welcome jsp requests wich ask for a parameter to display a different login according to the same parameter . For example if the user enters the url `"/parameter1"` (manual action ) , this variable shows me a personalized login  generated by a driver that cathes a RequestMapping ( value = " /{parameter}"from there, all URLS will have that parameter , the problem that I have is that when the user wishes to leave or your session expires , spring sends me the url `"/"` , but I need it to send me a `/parameter1` , in order to capture the parameter `"parameter1"` so that It leaves me in the custom login.  That way I would not have to manually re- enter the parameter . My security settings are as follows:

```
    <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myFilter" />
    <!-- <form-login login-page="/loginUser" login-processing-url="/testUser/j_spring_security_check"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginError"   default-target-url="/testUser"
        username-parameter="j_username" password-parameter="j_password" /> -->

    <logout invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" logout-success-url="/loginUser" logout-url="/testUser/j_spring_security_logout"/>

    <session-management invalid-session-url="/"   session-fixation-protection="migrateSession" >
       <concurrency-control max-sessions="2"  expired-url="/" error-if-maximum-exceeded="false"/>
    </session-management>
```

```
 <beans:bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:property  name="loginFormUrl" value="/loginUser" />
</beans:bean>  

<beans:bean id="myFilter" class="net.universia.test.autenticacionService.LoginAuthenticationFilter">
  <beans:property name="authenticationManager"  ref='UserauthenticationManager'/>
   <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureHandler"/>
   <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successHandler"/>   
   <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl"  value="/testUser/j_spring_security_check"/>
</beans:bean>

  <beans:bean  id = "exceptionTranslationFilter" class = "org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter" > 
    <beans:property  name = "authenticationEntryPoint"  ref = "loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" /> 
    <beans:property  name = "accessDeniedHandler"  ref = "accessDeniedHandler" /> 
  </beans:bean> 


<beans:bean id="successHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
   <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/testUser"/>
</beans:bean>
```

```
 <beans:bean  id = "accessDeniedHandler" class = "org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl" > 
    <beans:property  name = "errorPage"  value = "/403" /> 
 </beans:bean>
```

And the driver that displays the login form is:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/{testRef}", method = {RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})
public @ResponseBody ModelAndView loginTestRef(@PathVariable("testRef") String testRef,HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request) {

    session.setAttribute("ssidreffh", testRef);

    TestDatos test = testService.showTestUserByRef(testRef);

    request.getSession().setAttribute("test", test);

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/loginUser");
    mav.addObject("test", test);

    return mav;

}
```

If the user is in the url /dominio/parametro1/paginaPerfil goes or your session ends, spring redirect me to the url "/myApp/parameter1" 
and so would be in the login and not the root "/".

Answer (score -1):

I could finally resolve my problem. I implemented a custom filter for logging out with `SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler` and I could capture the previous URL and from that the parameter that I return with a redirect (`/parameter1`). This is my code:

```
public class CustomLogoutSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler  {
    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        String testRef = null;
        if (authentication != null) {
            String refererUrl = request.getHeader("Referer");
            System.out.println("variables: " +refererUrl);
            String[] parts = refererUrl.split("/");
            testRef = parts[5];
        }
        setDefaultTargetUrl("/"+testRef);
        super.onLogoutSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should translate your answer and format your code.

Comment: @Michaël I did it for them.